# All shells I have only display .lnk on my desktop and no existing folders?

Tags: bash, shell, directory, ls

I used commands like tree, dir, ls - all with -l tag.
all showing same - only .lnk files, labels to programs.
My desktop does have many folders, txt files.
It's not even showing txt files!

[image: w]

I tried all shell types - babun, win-bash, cygwin. All show same on desktop! Only .lnk files.
Only git-bash shows desktop folders and allows navigation. But it's slow!

[image: w2w2]

Comment: It seems to me a path problem. You are `ls` different paths because the contents are totally different.

Comment: @CSPei, i suspect same thing, u mean I should look into PATH variable in settings? settings of a shell or settings of variables in Control panel?

Comment: yes, Also `pwd` in each of your tool window to see what is the difference.